# Passing File Input Object of Child to Parent window in Javascript for IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

Is there any way that I can pass a DOM object of a file input from the child window to parent?
I tried to appendChild it works fine in Firefox but not in IE and when I use, innerHTML its not copying the value of the file to the parent but it was just creating the empty HTML file input element within the parent.

Appending Child (Works fine in IE but not Firefox)

```
var element = window.opener.document.getElementById("files_div");
element.parentNode.appendChild(document.getElementById("file0"));
```

InnerHTML(works fine everywhere but does not copy the entire object to parent)

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("files_div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("files_div").innerHTML;
```

I can't do this because of security reasons:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("file0").value = document.getElementById("file0").value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this stuff is resolved, instead of creating the file input in the Child and pass it to the parent window I created the input in the parent itself from the child's javascript.